# Convert DC 0 to +1V signal to -1 to +1 signal

Tags: signal

I need to convert a 0V to 1V measurement signal to -1 to +1 volt. What is the best way of achieving this? I've tried searching but can't seem to find anything relevant, as I'm not entirely sure what to search for.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change analog sensor signal to appropriate levels for microcontrollers?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169130/how-to-change-analog-sensor-signal-to-appropriate-levels-for-microcontrollers)

Comment: @kolosy not really, microcontrollers would have a bad day with negative voltages. This is more like analog signal conditioning more relevant to differential signal transmissions or things like audio signals which are 0V biased

Comment: @KyranF the application is different, but the problem seems the same - scaling one output voltage range to another.

Comment: @kolosy it is sort of similar, but more complicated than a simple resistor divider due to the negative voltages and difference in "scale" - aka, needs some form of gain.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the signal is; its characteristics (bandwidth, impedance), what the load is, accuracy requirements and the application?  They all affect the choice of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use an op-amp with dual-supplies, such as a rail-to-rail input AND output general purpose op-amp, with +-1.8V or +-3.3V supply rails.

Make a "summing amplifier" configuration, and offset ("add") the input signal with -0.5V, so the op-amp subtracts 0.5V from the input signal, making the output -0.5V -> +0.5V. You may use a resistor divider from the -ve supply rail to generate a -0.5V reference offset.

Next, with the output of the diff-amp, use a voltage follower/buffer op-amp (again, with dual supply rails) with a gain of 2, so the input is multiplied by 2.

This will result in the +-0.5V range of the difference amplifier becoming +-1V.

You did not state the bandwidth requirements for this application, so I assume a few 10's of KHz, and my advice here is relevant.

Comment: If the measurement signal varies (i.e, say it was 0.3v), would this method work to scale it +0.15 to -0.15?

Comment: This method will track the input voltage waveform, be it static, or changing, up to a certain "bandwidth". If the signal moves too fast, the op-amps slew rate may be too slow to catch up

Comment: you can probably combine the two op-amp stages btw, subtracting the 0.5V from the input and then gain of 2 on the output straight away

Comment: If the centre point is varying (for 0-1 it was 0.5V, for 0-0.3 you say you would want 0.15V), then you will need a circuit to find the mid point - which may be complex or simple depending on your signal.

Comment: @Firetramp oh right i get what you mean, Tom Carpenter's comment above is correct - you would need to modify the 'mid point' offset if you had a different type of signal.

Comment: The designer (you) need to know what the signal is going to be, and what you want it to become, before you can design these things. It's hard to make something adjust automatically